# NSUserDefaults: Is it possible to get userDefaults from another app?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

There are two apps installed on iPhone (myApp and competitorApp).competitorApp is saving user settings with using NSUserDefaults. I know all keys (value forKey) which using competitorApp. Is it possible to get values in myApp from competitorApp?

Comment: As of iOS 8, you can https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/shared-user-defaults-in-ios-3f15cd2c9409#.d9um8k7jc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the iOS App Programming Guide, [in the Security section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW7) you can read:

> For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences
>   and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of
>   fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files,
>   preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the
>   sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox
>   directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

That means that if you're not interested in jailbreaking, what you want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

No. Apps cannot access each other's user defaults, nor look inside each other's file system sandboxes. This is security working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreak.. Better solution to save userdefaults values on some server and then download it in another app. Not possible otherwise