# Modify defaults of sandboxed application from non-sandboxed app

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, sandbox

I have an application which I'm now sandboxing. I do automated acceptance testing using the accessibility API from a different process. Before sandboxing, the test suite used CFPreferencesSetValue and friends to set certain default values for the application.

After sandboxing, the defaults are read from ~/Library/Containers/BUNDLEID/Data/Library/Preferences but the CFPreferencesSetValue functions only writes to ~/Library/Preferences as far as I understand.

Is there a way to programmatically write preferences to the sandboxed preferences without e.g. hardcoding the location and modifying the plist directly, or using the defaults command line utility.

Comment: I have the same question. It must be possible somehow because the "defaults" command can access sandboxed prefs, e.g. "defaults read com.apple.Maps" in 10.9.

Comment: Actually, I cannot even read the sandboxed pref values from my non-sandboxed app. CFArrayRef prefs = CFPreferencesCopyKeyList (CFSTR("com.apple.Maps"), kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost) does not return any data, for instance, but the defaults command does. (Trying on 10.9.1)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add an "Application Group" to your sandboxed app, thereby allowing other apps of this group to share its preferences, see: [Reading NSUserDefaults from helper app in the sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014417/reading-nsuserdefaults-from-helper-app-in-the-sandbox?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a better way, see the answer to my own question here: [How does OS X's defaults command get access to prefs of sandboxed apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705279)

The trick is to use the full path to the preference file in the sandbox container, minus the ".plist" extension, as the application ID.