# How to Call a Private macOS CoreFoundation Function from Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsuserdefaults, core-foundation, iphone-privateapi

I'm looking for a way to use a private Apple API from within Swift code (namely, `_CFPreferencesCopyApplicationMap`, which allows you to look up the paths used for user defaults for any given application).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705279/how-does-os-xs-defaults-command-get-access-to-prefs-of-sandboxed-apps/62867428#62867428) answer for the motivation & the Objective-C solution. I was able to do this in Objective-C with the line:

```
extern CFDictionaryRef _CFPreferencesCopyApplicationMap(CFStringRef userName, CFStringRef hostName);
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do the same in Swift. I know it's possible to dynamically access ObjC objects at runtime using `NSClassFromString` or `NSSelectorFromString`, but as far as I can tell these can't be used with global C functions. `NSInvocation` likewise seems out.

Comment: The way you did it is correct. Use Objective C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is possible using [@_silgen_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35035099/1899706):

```
@_silgen_name("_CFPreferencesCopyApplicationMap")
func _CFPreferencesCopyApplicationMap(_: CFString!, _: CFString!) -> CFDictionary!

// Then, call as:
let applicationMap = _CFPreferencesCopyApplicationMap(kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost) as? [String: [URL]]
```