# NSUserDefaults from other application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to read values stored from other application but I couldnt figure it out yet. Then I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8939343/913571) which says its not possible. But I am trying to get values from Preferences Pane app to my own application.

If its not possible to read values using `NSUserDefaults` how should can these two communicate with each other(pref pane and a cocoa app) ?

EDIT: I also tried

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDef addSuiteNamed:@"com.foobar.pref"];
NSString *settingValue = [userDef stringForKey:@"settingValue"]; // returns nil
```

Comment: A preference pane is a kind of app. Are both created by you? Is it a system provided or 3rd part preference pane?

Comment: @uchuugaka yes I have created both a cocoa app and a preference pane app using Xcode 5 preference pane template.

Comment: @uchuugaka, a preference pane is not a kind of application, but a plug-in for the System Preferences app.

Comment: Pedantically yes. But basically, it's an application that runs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you found saying it's not possible was for iOS, not OS X.

I'm not sure if it is possible using `NSUserDefaults`, but you could certainly do it using `CFPreferencesSetAppValue` and `CFPreferencesCopyAppValue`.